# Entropy vs dimension of the Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, hilbert-space, temperature, entropy

In the definition of thermodynamic entropy $S=k\ln\Omega$ where $\Omega$ is the number of possible microstates of a given macrostate, we can also associate $\Omega$ with the dimension of the Hilbert space of our system, given the constraints of our macrostate.

However, the quantum harmonic oscillator has a finite entropy (at finite temperature) and an infinite Hilbert space, since there is an infinite number of allowed energy levels.

How does one reconcile this? Am I mistaken to think that $\Omega= \mbox{dim}(\mathcal{H})$?

Comment: Boltzmann's formula is valid for the microcanonical ensemble. Check its hypotheses on a classical/quantum system.

Answer (score 1):

The complete statement is that $\Omega$ is the number of possible microstates of a given macrostate **at fixed total energy**. The Hilbert space of the harmonic oscillator is infinite-dimensional due to the infinite (countable) basis. However, not all the states are compatible with the fixed energy condition. Only a finite number, thus explaining finite entropy and the fact that $\Omega \neq dim({\mathcal H})$.

Comment: thank you, this makes complete sense!